# PHP extension_dir (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu

Когда прописываю в консоли `php -i | grep extension_dir`, выдаёт путь

> extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20151012 => /usr/lib/php/20151012

хотя в `php.ini` прописано

> extension_dir="/usr/lib/php5/20121212/"

Почему так? Из-за этого *PHP* не видит мои расширения?

Comment: `php --ini` выведет тот .ini-файл, который вы редактирвоали?

Comment: php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.0/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,

Comment: выводит все связаное пхп 7 почему то

Comment: хотя у меня 5 стоит

Comment: так вот и редактируйте `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini`. текущую версию php можно посмотреть так: `php -v`.

Comment: а как сделать чтобы у меня 5 пхп активной была?

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/plesk/blog/306682/ update-alternatives